# ProxyConnectionError when connecting as Anonymous

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I have developed an operator to retrieve information from Orion Context Broker.

It works perfectly when I'm loggin but if I try to enter as anonymous (with the embedded URL) in a incognito window, the operator raises the next error:

(link to the image): https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxMkr.png

[image: Screenshot from console]

This is the code:

```
var doInitialSubscription = function doInitialSubscription() {

        this.subscriptionId = null;

        this.ngsi_server = MashupPlatform.prefs.get('ngsi_server');
        this.ngsi_proxy = MashupPlatform.prefs.get('ngsi_proxy');
        this.connection = new NGSI.Connection(this.ngsi_server, {
            ngsi_proxy_url: this.ngsi_proxy
        });

        console.log("Send initial subscription");

        var types = ['SMARTMETER'];
        var entityIdList = [];
        var entityId;
        entityId = {
            id: '.*',
            type: 'SMARTMETER',
            isPattern: true
        };
        entityIdList.push(entityId);
        var attributeList = null;
        var duration = 'PT3H';
        var throttling = null;
        var notifyConditions = [{
            'type': 'ONCHANGE',
            'condValues': condValues
        }];
        var options = {
            flat: true,
            onNotify: handlerReceiveEntity.bind(this),
            onSuccess: function (data) {
                console.log("Subscription success ID: "+data.subscriptionId);
                this.subscriptionId = data.subscriptionId;
                this.refresh_interval = setInterval(refreshNGSISubscription.bind(this), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2);  // each 2 hours
                window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
                    this.connection.cancelSubscription(this.subscriptionId);
                }.bind(this));
            }.bind(this),
            onFailure: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }

        };
        console.log("Now creating subscription...");
        this.connection.createSubscription(entityIdList, attributeList, duration, throttling, notifyConditions, options);
    };
```

Any idea of what is wrong?

Comment: please, provide request/response information (request headers, response headers, response body), thanks

Comment: Hi Álvaro, finally I solved the issue by upgrading the Orion to latest version following this link: http://bit.ly/17JUw4t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to user comments on the question, updating to Orion 0.19.0 (following the DB upgrade procedure detailed [here](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Upgrading_to_0.19.0_and_beyond_from_any_pre-0.19.0_version)) solves the problem.